# Best approach to manage parallel threads with a set of ip addresses using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executorservice, runnable

I have a set of 255 ip addresses to manage (x.x.x.1 -> x.x.x.255).
In Java if I check connection from my java mobile app with only one array of IP with a `setTimeout(200)` I could wait too much till finish all 255 ip addresses. On the other hand if I connect to at least one of those ip address I have some other things to do.
So my goal to reduce wait time on check if connection test works or fails is to split in a group of 15 parallel threads working at the same time where inside each of them I check 17 ip addresses.
In this way I made a class that implements Runnable where I execute something like:

```
HttpURLConnection con;
for(i=(currentThreadNumber*17)+1;i<(currentThreadNumber*17)+17;i++) { 
    String ipToCheckConnection = maskIP+"."+i;
    String loginURL = "http://" + ipToLogin + "/....";
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(loginURL);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(100);
        con.connect();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            con.disconnect();
            do something else with this IP....
        }

    } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
        continue;
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

In my main function inside a button click event I implement:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
```

then I tried various way to execute parallel jobs calling the runnable class waiting all threads are finished before to continue and exit from button click event, like using `CountDownLatch` , `.awaitTermination`... I tried also to use `.invokeAll` but it doesn't work with runnable but with callable... but I encounter the issue how to pass to runnable class current thread count like 0,1,2,3,..so I can pass to the `for(...)` inside runnable...
What would be best approach to pass this current thread count like 0,1,2,3,.. to the runnable class?
Or is there a better different way than using ExecutorService which I read everywhere it's the simplest way to work parallel threads with?...

Thanks!
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something as follows:

- initialize the `CountDownLatch` and `ExecutorService` with the number of desired workers
- on the loop of assigning work to the workers pass the current task number
- each worker should also call `countDownLatch.countDown();` after having terminated the work to signal that to the other workers that might be waiting
- the main thread should call `countDownLatch.await();` to wait for the remaining workers to finish their work.

The code could look like the following:

```
public class WaitForAllToEnd {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int total_threads = 15;
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(total_threads);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(total_threads);
        for(int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++){
            final int thread_id = i;
            executor.execute(parallelWork(thread_id, countDownLatch));
        }
        countDownLatch.await();
        System.out.println("Exit");
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private static Runnable parallelWork(int thread_id, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                // Some code logic
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Do Something
            }
            // Some code logic
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        };
    }
}
```